# Are there any security problems to running an http server using Python's built in module?

Tags: server, python, security, cgi

I have a presentation to make to a few people. It's interactive with python CGI scripts. Are there any security problems with using **python3 -m http.server --cgi 8000**? Each person will be using their own computer to access this server (which is pointed at my computer's network IP) and my form entries are all properly escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source of [`/usr/lib/python3.3/http/server.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/http/server.py):

> **SECURITY WARNING**: DON'T USE THIS CODE UNLESS YOU ARE INSIDE A FIREWALL
>   -- it may execute arbitrary Python code or external programs.